# ¿Como hacer clic en un reCaptcha con JS?

Tags: javascript, html5, recaptcha

Tengo el problema que requiero poder hacer clic en un **reCaptcha** de una forma automática para agilizar cargas de contenidos, pero solo eso hacer clic en la casilla si corre con suerte de que no exige verificación por imagen debería proceder. Mi código actual funciona cuando quiere porque mayormente arroja un error de elemento no encontrado o que no presenta la función `click()`

**Código:**

```js
document.querySelector("#rc-anchor-container").click();
```

En si lo que hace esta pequeña fracción es localizar la casilla con el **ID** definido y hacer clic pero a veces resultas como otras no y arroja este **error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Sino hasta que manualmente selecciono el elemento con las **herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome**.

Creo que el problema se encuentra en el que **reCaptcha** se encuentra dentro de un `<iFrame`:

```html
<iframe class="" id="captcha-internal" src="https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/challenge/captchaInternal" frameborder="0" role="presentation" title="Pregunta captcha" height="150" width="304"></iframe>
```

**Gracias** y espero su apoyo.